# Why do some sheet-music arrangements harmonize anticipation notes?

Tags: harmony, nonchord-tones

[image]

Throughout this arrangement from the song "Don't look back in anger" by the band "Oasis" the arranger seems to harmonize the anticipated melody note as shown in green. But the actual song has chord changes on beat 1. Why would any arranger change this ?I can't hear any sonic benefit by anticipating the harmonization along with the melody. Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: I would note that the rhythm of the melody as written here is not what Noel sings on the original, it's not as 'straight' as this. While I think it would be difficult to notate down exactly as it was sung (as it's so loose, in a good way) I think that would also point towards this particular transcription being very over simplified!

Comment: I'm afraid the question _why_ might be unanswerable. That's an artistic choice the arranger made. Maybe they believed it would sound better this way in a piano arrangement? Maybe it's a mistake? Or maybe they thought the right hand rhythm would be too difficult to play for some players if the chord came on beat 1?

Answer (score 11):

This has been an element of certain popular music styles since at least the end of the 19th century.  For example, you can see it in Scott Joplin's *Maple Leaf Rag,* published in 1899.

The "sonic benefit" is that it emphasizes the syncopated rhythm, especially by virtue of the contrast between the syncopated right hand and the "straight" bass in the left hand.

Comment: Ok I understand... although I wonder why Oasis didnt think of that.. or maybe the point is to let the rhythm of the vocal line be the element in the composition that is syncopated and whoever arranged it like this decided that this sounded better for solo piano and voice

Comment: @armani the end of that last sentence is probably what it is. Also bear in mind that Oasis may have decided a big push was a bit naff or dated. They are not trained musicians, they don't read music and I don't think they know much theory, they'll have a rough idea for a song and then it develops organically through the band rehearsing. I doubt they would have written it down or worked out where to push at any point! "maybe the point is to let the rhythm of the vocal line be the element in the composition that is syncopated", probably, but I doubt Oasis would have thought of it like that!

Comment: Ok thank you! I will say that while on the surface a band like Oasis might not be musically trained a lot of the time producers that work with artists are and after studying much of their songs, there are some uncanny logical patterns in their songwriting at which it would be impossible to arrive consistently purely by chance. I can assure you that their music has at least had some kind of input from someone with some idea about music theory.

Comment: @armani I think you'd be surprised, firstly at how little theory input is received, and also how much can be absorbed through the oral tradition of playing many many other songs! You also may be surprised how little music theory the people who recorded bands like oasis had. As I worked with the same group of musicians and producers who recorded all this stuff, including this album. The producers etc certainly don't know theory in the way you or I may talk about it, most don't know the major scale (really). However thats not to say they don't have a huge built up catalog of techniques.

Comment: ...and a sort of uncanny sixth sense for what sounds great, original, clunky, messy etc. They are very very skilled people, and over those years I learned so much about where making a great record differs from knowing lots about music academically. They do it much more on feel and vibe, sometimes making odd decisions that really work, sometimes finding some quite classic sounds via intuition and instinct rather than formal knowledge. I was in that business for many years and met very few who had any formal training, from band through to producer and everyone in between, I was an anomaly!

Comment: So, I can be almost certain they didn't have any input from someone who knows theory, and they really would shy away from that too. However that by no means means it's pure chance! It's standing on the shoulders of giants, being obsessed with music and playing 100's of Beatles, Beach Boys, Dylan songs etc and learning sounds. Not really knowing what they were called but adding them to the growing pile of techniques. Thats why their writing sounds so 'classic', like much great art it's constructed from pieces of what came before :)

Comment: @OwenM - You missed out Slade.. but I'll give you the rest, for sure ;)))

Comment: @Owen: Well of course I can't prove that you are wrong but If I am to consider all my analysis of Oasis songs to date I would need a tall order of conflicting evidence to shy me away from my firm belief that they had some musical theory input from somewhere. Thank you for sharing your experience!

Comment: We used to have a trained MD in the studio, but we'd almost ridicule him for using terms like 'polychord' when to us it was just 'refusing to change the vocal harmonies just because the rest moved a bit'.

Comment: @Tetsujin oh my, how could I forget Slade!

Comment: @armani - the same has long been said of the Beatles… who were *far* more complex on occasion. They had a fully-competent producer to help them out, but he didn't write Yesterday, only scored it after the fact. Sometimes 'idiot savant' is  just that.

Comment: And remember, artists like Noel and any high paid celebrity will NEVER own up to the fact that they had help in their songs just like any high paid celebrity would ever admit to getting a hair transplant to stop balding

Comment: @armani Well I don't think this is an academic debate where you need to prove me wrong. But I'm from that world, I know the people who recorded that album, my boss (and mentor as an audio engineer) worked on that album, I worked out of the studio that recorded that album, it was my income for many years recording similar bands. I KNOW it's how I say because I was there, you can choose to disbelieve me but that seems a little silly, and if you accept that maybe I am correct then you could, if you like, start to explore other ways of analysing music other than just the traditional theoretical!

Comment: Well Noel wasn't a high paid celebrity at the time of this album being written, and it's not just him, it's all the other similar bands who never get famous but record great albums that never do anything. I've seen all those too, they also don't have help, they also come to some great songs sometimes with some very classic techniques that take a bit of theory to explain. Trust me, there is not a covert music theory helper service in the music industry :)

Comment: and I'm with @OwenM - though my studio experience was with different people, possibly 15 years earlier, the similarities are greater than the differences. As I've probably mentioned [more than once/ad nauseam ;) in this stack before, I worked with, amongst others, Pete Waterman in his mid-period [between 2Tone & PWL] - as well as all the others connected to that same period/genre [Kershaw, Toyah, Crass, Bjørk were all linked, like a bacon number;). Sure, there was always ONE trained muso in the studio, but that was well after all the songs were written & main arrangement elements designed.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Is Bjørk a Norwegian rip-off of Björk? ;-)

Comment: @psmears - LOL, yup. My poor attempt at trying to remember just how it was spelled ;))

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a practical choice by the arranger. The melody is syncopated and the chords fall on the beat in the recording but from a pianist’s perspective in a piano arrangement it would be a bit awkward to play the melody on the 4& and the chord on 1 in the same hand. The arranger has the bass note land on 1 to take away the completely syncopated feeling. Subjectively I think it would sound a little strange to split the rhythms in one hand compared to how it is written. Try playing it with the lower ties on the E and A notes removed. I think you’ll agree.

Answer (score 2):

In that particular case (and many others) that's exactly what happens on the track. The chord changes are on the 1st beat of each bar, whereas the vocals are 'pushed', that's to say they come just where the dots show on the music.

Some songs do actually change chord just before the next bar, usually along with the vocals, accompanied either by an up strum on that last bit of the bar, or an early down strum at the same place (on guitar).

Comment: Yes, the vocals are "pushed" as you say but not the harmony as is the case in this arrangment. That is why I am asking. IOW: Why would this modification have been made

Comment: The entire arrangement is massively simplified. Maybe they just thought it would be easier to play. The guitar in the original does a push, though it's a bit too muted to know whether it actually pushes the chord change or not [practically, it's likely to, to save a very fast change], but the piano plods pretty much right the way through playing four to the floor.

Comment: Tetsujin. The guitar strums with the chord change happening on the downbeat. I know this because 1. I can hear it 2. because they play it like that in acoustic versions and 3. because another arrangement that features the guitar transcriptions (which should be very true to the guitar part) shows the actual guitar pattern used in the song.

Comment: Right the way through there are straight 1's, pushes on the 4 and pushes on the 4&. They're not strict, they happen 'whenever he feels like it' but it's part of the groove. That score is still a huge oversimplification & I would not look at it as 'gospel' it's just what the arranger decided would be simplest. Don't get hung up on it.

Comment: Tetsujin. If that is the case, the odd change or inconsistencies of rhythm should not be the one that the arrangement gets based on unless the arranger here is just doing what he/she thinks sounds good and not listening or respecting the groove of the song. Nothing in music is strict but the groove in the song is not this... it has been changed and I think my question stands. My only guess is that the arranger made it like this to try and give more movement between the L & R hand parts which is basically what Phoog said

Comment: @Tetsujin - doesn't sound to me like the guitar is pushing. Vox, yes, guitar, no.

Comment: Not on that one specific word, no - but it's a commonality through the verses; the arranger is perhaps covering that the snare is insistently on that 4&, and for a beginner is just easier to play. Let's be honest, it's a simplistic arrangement trying to cover in 2 hands what an entire band is doing [& frankly, failing]. I really don't think it's worth all this detailed analysis. It's a "beginner's guide to Oasis" & little else. It's only the insistence of the OP that keeps drawing us back in ;)

Comment: Actually has nothing to do with Oasis... it is an arranging question, which Phoog has already answered IMO

Comment: @armani - I think we've gone far past 'answering the question' & we're now down to 'who agrees with me?'. It seems you won't accept the opinion of anyone who doesn't, even now so far as to deny the question is about Oasis… which is has been right up to now. If you want to generalise, you need to ask a general question, not hark on about one aspect of one arrangement until it [& we] are exhausted.. then change the subject.